# Frida Java.array on string array fail after casting from object

Tags: java, frida

I tried to iterate all strings from String[] using that code, but in all my tries it failed with error

```
let str = ""
let obj_ = Java.cast(obj, Java.use("[Ljava.lang.String;"));

console.log("obj: " + JSON.stringify(obj))
console.log("obj after cast: " + JSON.stringify(obj_))

try {
    let arr = Java.array('java.lang.String', obj_)
} catch (e) {
    console.log("error 1: " + e)
}

try {
    let arr = Java.array('[Ljava.lang.String;', obj_)
} catch (e) {
    console.log("error 2: " + e)
}

try {
    let arr = Java.array('java.lang.String', obj)
} catch (e) {
    console.log("error 3: " + e)
}

try {
    let arr = Java.array('[Ljava.lang.String;', obj)
} catch (e) {
    console.log("error 4: " + e)
}

// for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
//     str = str + obj_[i] + ","
// }
console.log("str: " + str + " | length: " + obj_.length)
return obj_.toString()
```

result:

```
obj: "<instance: java.lang.Object, $className: [Ljava.lang.String;>"
obj after cast: "<instance: [Ljava.lang.String;>"
error 1: Error: Expected an array
error 2: Error: Expected an array
error 3: Error: Expected an array
error 4: Error: Expected an array
str:  | length: undefined
```

I used four try catch to find if any of those method would work, but with no luck.

Comment: Friday's `Java.array` method wants the component type as first arg. Thus, `Java.array('[Ljava....')` makes no sense, that would make a `String[][]`. Also, that value makes no sense; `[L` is binaryspeak, and requires slashes: `[Ljava.lang.String;` is meaningless; at best it should be `[Ljava/lang/String;`

Comment: I'm not personally familiar with Frida, it could be that `[Ljava.lang.String;` is some frida-specific invention, but if it is, that is utterly bizarre.

Comment: In my understanding `Java.array(..)` requires a JavaScript array as second parameter. It is designed to make an JavaScript array that can be used when calling a Java method. So I don't think it can be used to cast a Java object to an array. BTW: where does `obj` come from? Of what type is `obj`?

Comment: @Robert it's from .invoke method first argument, so its object

Comment: also you have any other ideas how to iterate String[] then?

Comment: I am not sure what is your problem. I have an app which has a method `public byte[] String processStringArray(String[] array)`. If I hook this method in Frida `activityClass.processStringArray.implementation = function(data) {...` . No cast or something else needed to access data. I can simply execute `data.length` or get the entry `data[i]` in a loop. Please provide a minimal reproducible example of Frida code and the mthod name and signature of the method you have hooked.

Comment: @Robert Yeah but i have it casted from Object, i dont have in method String[] arr, i have Object

Comment: Please add the method signature of the Java method you have hooked and the hooking code. Without it is very hard to understand your question.

Comment: @Robert public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args) its from java.lang.reflect